# Save url CSV to CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I extract some data from a url but I can't create a csv with that. When I try to save it into a csv each character is in a row and not in a cell...

```
import csv
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('url', 'pass'))
a = requests.get('url2', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('url', 'pass'))

b = a.text
a = b.replace('"', '')
f = a.replace('%', '')
g = f.replace('.','')
z = g.replace(',', '.')
zz = z.replace(';',',')

with open('jj.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(zz)
>>> zz
```

Data:

```
Tuky,Fecha,Bid_requests,Bid_responses_won,Fill_rate,Bid_responses_won_clearing_price,Bid_responses_won_clearing_income,aaaP,17/01/2018,41325955,22453,0.05,3.97,89.17
```

This is my saved csv:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
with open('jj.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(zz.split(","))
```

This will create a list from your string, split at `','` - `writerows` takes an iterable and writes it into the file -  a string is also iterable, thats why you gett each character seperately.

Read up on it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import csv
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('url', 'pass'))
a = requests.get('url2', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('url', 'pass'))

b = a.text
a = b.replace('"', '')
f = a.replace('%', '')
g = f.replace('.','')
z = g.replace(',', '.')
zz = z.replace(';',',')
zz = zz.split('.')

with open('jj.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows([zz])
```

**Explanation**
You need to pass a 2 dimensional array to write rows, in this case you only have one row so we pass [zz] to writer.writerows. zz itself should be an array where each element is a new column, which we achieve by doing zz.split('.')